# Como generar el build de producción de Astro.js con un path relativo para las importaciones?

Tags: javascript, html, build

Pasa lo siguiente, tengo un proyecto que migre de Js y Jquery puro hacia Astro.js, en local todo ya funciona correctamente, el punto es que al generar el build de producción, todas las importaciones ya sea de archivos CSS o de imágenes, no cambian a un path relativo, por lo que al subir la página al servidor, esta no carga ningún estilo o imagen. Tengo entendido que Astro hace esto automáticamente, pero no logro entender en donde estoy cometiendo el error? Debo hacer una configuración extra en el archivo astro.config.js?

Las importaciones de los archivos CSS las hago mediante "import" en los archivos .astro y las imágenes están en la carpeta public importandolas mediante la etiqueta de img utilizando el path con src

Desde ya agradezco por tomarse el tiempo de leer mi problema, Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

he empezado con Astro recientemente, ya he hecho 2 proyectos pero no los habia desplegado, pense que todo estaba bien porque en local funcionan perfecto, pero la verdad es que hago build y desde ya el "dist" no le funcionan los estilos ni nada, mi proyecto tiene tailwind y css y ves que los elementos tienen las clases pero la web no tiene estilos, he hecho de todo, he subido el proyecto a github pages, a netlify y a un hosting compartido, pero el problema no es del sitio donde se aloja, es que al hacer build ya tiene el problema, (disculpa que vaya en forma de pregunta, soy nuevo y necesito 50 de reputacion para comentar )

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/402481)

Answer (score 0):

El problema debe estar en tu jquery, ponlo en la carpeta public y al momento de referenciarlo lo pones ejemplo:  
detro del la carpeta public en este caso yo cree una carpeta scripts, y los script como el jquery.min.js u otros archivos lo referencias y luego generas el build y la carpeta dist lo publicas,e importante cuando publiques revisa tus mensajes de error

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Tenía un problema similar, aquí dejo algunas posibles soluciones:

imágenes: colocar `<img src="/photo.webp" alt="description" />` y la imagen la guardas dentro de la carpeta "public"

importación js y css al correr build: tal vez el problema sea la ruta generada dentro de tu archivo index.html al correr npm run build

mi archivo astro.config.mjs es:

```
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
    integrations: [tailwind()],
    outDir: "./docs",
    build: {
        assets: "a",
    },
});
```

con esto logro:
archivo de salida: "docs" en vez de "dist" (hay preferencia en github pages)
en la importacon de estilos dentro del .html de salida se obtiene `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./a/index.BRQT5ggN.css" />` en vez de `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_astro/index.BRQT5ggN.css" />` logrando que el servidor donde deployes (en mi caso github pages) encuentre el css, y de igual modo el js